# Error message was not delivered - failed message is null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a spring integration flow with a poller cron whose goal is to initialize directories and mongodb collections. If the initializer flow throws a RuntimeException, the framework sends a message to the errorChannel. The error flow take in charge the message but something wrong:

```
2017-04-07 06:25:00.484 |  |  |  | [taskScheduler-8] | DEBUG | com.objectway.bacco.integration.flow.InitializerIntegrationFlowConfiguration | cleanTmp | INITIALIZATION - Directory bacco created
2017-04-07 06:25:04.857 |  |  |  | [taskScheduler-9] | ERROR | org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler | handleMessageInternal | org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: The path [/tmp/bacco/bank_ftp/00082] does not denote a properly accessible directory.
    at org.springframework.integration.file.DefaultDirectoryScanner.listFiles(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:83)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.scanInputDirectory(FileReadingMessageSource.java:293)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.receive(FileReadingMessageSource.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:59)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:175)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:57)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:176)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:173)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:324)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2017-04-07 06:25:04.882 |  |  |  | [taskScheduler-9] | INFO | com.objectway.bacco.service.logging.logback.LogServiceLogback | info | null | null | null | ERROR - Processing error
2017-04-07 06:25:04.930 |  |  |  | [taskScheduler-9] | WARN | org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler | handleError | Error message was not delivered.
org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:176)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler.handleError(MessagePublishingErrorHandler.java:85)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:324)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.java:90)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:89)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:220)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:51)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:87)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:267)
    at com.objectway.bacco.integration.component.analytics.ProcessTransformer.evaluateExpression(ProcessTransformer.java:118)
    at com.objectway.bacco.integration.component.analytics.ProcessTransformer.retrieveValueByKey(ProcessTransformer.java:115)
    at com.objectway.bacco.integration.component.analytics.ProcessTransformer.transform(ProcessTransformer.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:347)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:166)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:155)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:93)
```

From the documentation **F.4 When Exceptions occur in a scheduled poller task’s execution, those exceptions will be wrapped in ErrorMessages and sent to the errorChannel as well.**
Is the ErrorMessages the problem? I found the ErrorMessage class but not the ErrorMessages.

Thank you

**EDIT:** the failedMessage is null. How is it possible?

```
@Bean
public MessageSource<?> dateMessageSource() {
    MethodInvokingMessageSource source = new MethodInvokingMessageSource();
    source.setObject( new SystemTime() );
    source.setMethodName( "getTime" );
    return source;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow initIntegrationFlow( ProcessTransformer processTransformer,
                                            MongoCleanerService mongoCleanerService,
                                            ControlComponentService controlComponentService,
                                            DirectoryService directoryService,
                                            @Value( "${output.directory}" ) String outputDirectory,
                                            @Qualifier( DAILY_POLLER ) PollerSpec pollerSpec ) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from( dateMessageSource(), c -> c.poller( pollerSpec ) )
            .enrichHeaders( headerEnricherSpec -> headerEnricherSpec.headerFunction( CORRELATION_ID, message -> "00000" )
                    .headerFunction( NETWORK, message -> "-ALL-" )
                    .headerFunction( GROUP, message -> "ALL" )
                    .headerFunction( DOMAIN, ( message ) -> ( INIT ) ) )
            .transform( new FlowLogger()
                    .level( INFO )
                    .expression( "'INITIALIZATION - Start Initializer, drop collections and temporary files'" )
                    .logService( logService ) )
            .transform( processTransformer )
            .handle( ( payload, headers ) -> {
                controlComponentService.manageComponent( "ftpExportFlow", "start" );
                mongoCleanerService.clean();
                directoryService.cleanTmp( outputDirectory );
                return new InitializationMessage();
            } )
            .channel( INITIALIZED_CHANNEL )
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow endWithErrorFlowBean( ProcessRepository processRepository,
                                             AnalyticsService analyticsService,
                                             LogService logService ) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from( IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME )
            .transform( new FlowLogger().level( INFO ).expression( "'ERROR - Processing error'" )
                    .logService( logService ) )
            .transform( new ProcessTransformer()
                    .processRepository( processRepository )
                    .analyticsService( analyticsService )
                    .processStatusType( ProcessStatusType.PROCESS_WITH_ERROR ) )
            .transform( source -> {
                controlBus.sendCommand( "@ftpExportFlow.stop()" );
                return processRepository.findByProcessStatusType( ProcessStatusType.PROCESS_WITH_ERROR );
            } )
            .filter( processes -> ( ( List<Process> ) processes ).size() == 1 )
            .channel( REPORT_INPUT_CHANNEL )
            .get();
}
```

Comment: It's a typo; it should be `ErrorMessage`s - you need to show your configuration for anyone to help with this, and show the full stack trace.

Comment: You should always make a comment when you supply more information. We don't get notified of edits.

Answer (score 2):

The failure is before a message has been created - hence the `null` `failedMessage`.

> 2017-04-07 06:25:04.857 |  |  |  | [taskScheduler-9] | ERROR | org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler | handleMessageInternal | org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: The path [/tmp/bacco/bank_ftp/00082] does not denote a properly accessible directory.

You only get a `failedMessage` property after a message has been created - typically when an error occurs in the downstream flow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
But, Is this line IntegrationFlows.from( dateMessageSource(), c -> c.poller( pollerSpec ) ) creating a message? The exception is thrown after into the handle.

Comment: No; the poller polls the message source if there is a file to process it sends a message; if there's no file, it does nothing. If the message source throws an exception (such as your bad directory) there is no message to include in the `ErrorMessage`. You are getting a secondary exception while trying to process that message.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give you an explanation. The init's goal is to clean the environment (mongo and tmp directories). The poller starts every day (mon-fri) at 6:25 am and the dateMessageSouce() creates a message with a new Date as payload . It is not a file polling, it's only a trigger. The exception is thrown by a service invoked into the handle.

Comment: Well, __you are not showing the whole picture__ - clearly your init flow source is simple and will always return a message. However, the stack trace __clearly__ shows a file source, which is failing `FileReadingMessageSource.scanInputDirectory...` and it is __THAT__ failure that your error flow is not handling properly because __ITS__ failure is before a message was created. You must have another polled (file reading) source in your application. You should handle all errors or segregate your error channels.

Comment: Great deal! Thank you!